# Install GLEW with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, glew

I'm trying to install GLEW with Code::Blocks. Here is what I've done to install and use it:

1. I've downloaded GLEW [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/?source=typ_redirect)
2. I've opened the downloaded zip file and copied all the files in `glew-2.0.0.zip\glew-2.0.0\include\GL` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\GL`.
3. To compile GLEW, I created a new project in Code::Blocks using New->Project->Static library. In that project, I deleted main.c and added the three .c files in `glew-2.0.0.zip\glew-2.0.0\src`. Then I clicked on Build and got a libglew.a file that I copied into `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib`.
4. In my C++ Project, I clicked on Project->Build Options.
5. In the Compiler Settings tab in the #defines tab, I wrote`GLEW_STATIC` like this:
   [image: screenshot]
6. In the Linker settings tab of the Build options, I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglew.a`.
7. In the beginning of my project, I wrote `#include <GL/glew.h>` to include GLEW.
8. To initialize GLEW, I wrote `GLenum initialisationGLEW(glewInit());` in main.cpp (I've already initialized SDL and OpenGL).

The problem is that when I try to compile my project, I get the following errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglew.a(glew.o): In function `glewInit_GL_VERSION_1_3':
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:7538: undefined reference to`wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:7539: undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:7540: undefined reference to`wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:7541: undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:7542: undefined reference to`wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglew.a(glew.o):C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:7543: more undefined references to `wglGetProcAddress@4' follow
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglew.a(glew.o): In function`glewContextInit':
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:13470: undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:13530: undefined reference to`glGetIntegerv@8'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:13539: undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:13593: undefined reference to`_glewInit_GL_VERSION_1_2'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglew.a(glew.o): In function `glewInit_WGL_3DL_stereo_control':
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:15973: undefined reference to`wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglew.a(glew.o): In function `glewInit_WGL_AMD_gpu_association':
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:15986: undefined reference to`wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:15987: undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:15988: undefined reference to`wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:15989: undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglew.a(glew.o):C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:15990: more undefined references to`wglGetProcAddress@4' follow
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglew.a(glew.o): In function `wglewGetExtension@4':
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:16473: undefined reference to`wglGetCurrentDC@0'
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglew.a(glew.o): In function `wglewInit@0':
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:16486: undefined reference to`wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:16487: undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
>   C:/Users/dduck/Desktop/glew/glew.c:16495: undefined reference to`wglGetCurrentDC@0'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

It says that these errors are in the file `C:\Users\dduck\Desktop\glew\glew.c`, one of the files that I compiled to get libglew.a, but they come from my C++ project, not when I try to compile libglew.a. I managed to compile libglew.a without any problem. So the project in which I get this error doesn't contain `C:\Users\dduck\Desktop\glew\glew.c`, it only contains `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglew.a`. What's even more strange is that I tried to delete `C:\Users\dduck\Desktop\glew\glew.c` and the compiler still said that there was en error in that file. I also tried to download an already compiled version of libglew.a [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/f6pr6u79ggj5r53/libglew32s.a) and use it instead of the version that I compiled. Then something even more strange happened: the compiler said that there was an error (the same as the one I got for my version of libglew.a) in the file `C:\Users\pb\Documents\dotA\glew.c`, a file that has never existed on my computer.

What am I doing wrong? Why do I get errors in files that aren't part of the project and that sometimes don't even exist? What can I do to fix it?

**Edit:**

I tried to also add `opengl32` in Linker Settings and then I only got one error:

> C:\Users\dduck\Desktop\glew\glew.c|13593|undefined reference to `_glewInit_GL_VERSION_1_2'|

Comment: Hint: `wgl*` functions in your error log reside in opengl32.dll - (libopengl32.a). See more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374386(v=vs.85).aspx (add "opengl32" to the libs tab of the build options too)

Comment: @enhzflep That changed something but didn't solve the problem. Now, instead of getting all these errors I only get one error that says `C:\Users\dduck\Desktop\glew\glew.c|13593|undefined reference to _glewInit_GL_VERSION_1_2'|` (which is still in a file that no longer exists).

Comment: well, a quick google indicates that to be a function.(I'd expected it to be a #define) So presumably, you _should_ still have the file that contains it. If it was part of the original archive, re-extract it. Otherwise, go hunting for the file. It sounds like it'll init GL, to function as it did in version 1.2 - if you look at SetPixelFormat (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd369049(v=vs.85).aspx) You can see that it needs to have a version passed to it. So, I guess the function sets this appropriatly, then calls `wglCreateContext` - find that original file!

Comment: @enhzflep What's that file called?

Comment: no idea. You said `(which is still in a file that no longer exists)` At this point, I'm wondering how can you possibly know this if you've no idea which file the function resides in? Hmmmm. Anyhow, have a look around. Search for: `undefined reference to _glewInit_GL_VERSION_1_2` - seems likely others have had the same problem. Dunno - I never used GLEW - too much of a pain in the posterior - I just used the functions Windows provides and then replicated the functionality of GLEW that I wanted.

Comment: @enhzflep The "file that no longer exists" is C:\Users\dduck\Desktop\glew\glew.c. But that one I've compiled along with two others (glewinfo.c and visualinfo.c) so all the functions that are in there should be in libglew.a which I included in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have done it, but make sure that in your linker you link these files:

```
glu32
glew32 
opengl32
```

So, I know that you want to use glew32 static version, but first make sure that the dynamic version is working. Just get glew's .dll files into the folder with your executables. If it doesn't work, make sure that glews include folder is in your compilers include folder ( idk why, it just works like that ).